# How to add aggregation function to non grouped column which is not in select

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table `tab`, which contains columns `a,b,c,d`. But the following query will not work since the `c` is not in the group by clause or in a reduction function.

```
SELECT a, b, c FROM tab GROUP BY a, b;
```

But what i want is to select `c` based on maximum value of `d`. How can I do this query in PostgreSQL ?.

```
| a | b | c | d   |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 100 |
| 1 | 2 | 4 | 110 |
| 1 | 2 | 5 | 90  |
```

As the output I need the result in row 2, because the value in d is the highest.

Comment: Please [edit] your question add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. _Formatted_ text please, no [screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: What if there is 2 values with the same `d` like `1,2,3,100` and `1,2,4,100`? Do you want both?

Comment: @lad2025, good point :).. i think i should have only one. Then I need another criteria to filter that out as well. But again its another problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Classic `top-n-per-group`. One way to do it using `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
WITH
CTE
AS
(
    SELECT
        a, b, c
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY a, b ORDER by d DESC) AS rn
    FROM tab
)
SELECT
    a, b, c
FROM CTE
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Index on `(a, b, d, c)` should help.

Approach with `ROW_NUMBER` works well when a table has few rows per group and the server has to read most of the table. For example, a table has 1 million rows and 800K distinct groups of `(a, b)`. You'd have to read most rows any way.

If the table has 1 million rows and only 20 distinct groups of `(a, b)` it would be better to do 20 seeks of an appropriate index instead of reading all rows.

Comment: Correct and standard compliant. And use `RANK` or `DENSE_RANK` instead, if you want to consider ties.

Answer (score 3):

In Postgres, you can use `distinct on`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (a, b) a, b, c
FROM tab
ORDER BY a, b, d DESC;
```

This syntax is specific to Postgres.  It is often the most efficient way to do this type of operation.

Answer (score 0):

if you have a primary key,
you can select max d in a sub query and inner join that query on primary.

Comment: It is correct that you can select `max(d)` per `a, b` and use this to access the records in question. This has nothing to do with the table having a primary key or not, however.

Comment: you need some identical value for join, that was what i meant.

Comment: Well, you get `a, b, max(d)` and join with `a, b, d` of course :-)